# Java class could not find or load main class in Linux, but Windows ok

Tags: java, linux, process

Using process builder to launch other Java applications in their own OS process. The implementation works on Windows 7, but not on Linux. Both machines are using Java 1.7. Here is some example code:

```
//Windows OK, but Linux Could not find or load main class 
//weka.subspaceClusterer.MySubspaceClusterEvaluation 

ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
commands.add("java");
commands.add("-cp");
commands.add("\".:lib/*\"");
commands.add("weka.subspaceClusterer.MySubspaceClusterEvaluation");
procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
procBuilder.inheritIO();
procBuilder.command(commands);
Process proc = procBuilder.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue on Mac OS X. It worked in Terminal but not in Eclipse. It worked for me if I removed quotes around the class path string. I guess Eclipse JVM does not like it when there are quotes around any of the arguments passed to ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Thanks. It is now so long ago that I don't remember how it worked out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The classpath separator is `;` under Windows, but `:` under Unix.

Consider creating a runnable jar, where your classpath is stored in the MANIFEST.MF entry, so you can just execute `java -jar whatever.jar`.

Comment: He is using : in Linux.  I agree about the manifest, but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I created an executable jar using Eclipse. The executable jar runs on Windows. On Linux, it continues not to be able to find the class MySubspaceClusterEvaluation.

Comment: An executable jar must be started with "java -jar foo.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.  It just can't find your class file.  Try setting the working directory of your process:

```
procBuilder.directory(new File("package/structure/starts/here"));
```

Comment: I tried directory() to set the root of the package structure, but it did not solve the problem. I do not know much about Java and its security model. Could the JVM be preventing the process I forked from accessing the class file for security reasons?